# Seleccionar texto con Mouse de un Textbox

Tags: c#

consulta, que propiedad inhabilita, es decir que no permita la seleccion con el mouse del texto o valor que contiene un TextBox, hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

muchas gracias

Comment: Que utilizas , Windows Forms o WPF?. Además indica el código que tengas en la pregunta, así será mas facil responderte.

Answer (score 0):

En principio, no existe ninguna propiedad para control `TextBox` que haga directamente lo que quieres hacer. Aun así, podrías utilizar la propiedad [SelectionLength](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_SelectionLength) en el evento `Click` del `TextBox`:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).SelectionLength = 0;
}
```